# Why does implicit conversion to int convert and truncate decimal?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    C.F();
}
public class C
{
    public static void F()
    {
        var a = new A { i = 1, d = 2.5m };
        var b = new B(a);
        I(b);
        D(b);
    }
    static void I(int i) { Console.WriteLine("int is: " + i); }  
    static void D(decimal d) { Console.WriteLine("decimal is: " + d); }
}
public class A
{
    public int i;
    public decimal d;
}
public class B
{
    A _a;
    public B(A a) { _a = a; }
    public static implicit operator int(B b) { return b._a.i; }
    public static implicit operator decimal(B b) { return b._a.d; }
}
```

OUTPUT:
**int is: 1
decimal is: 2.5**

Comment out:

```
//public static implicit operator decimal(B b) { return b._a.d; }
```

OUTPUT:
**int is: 1
decimal is: 1**

What is going on when the second version runs and outputs 1 for both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the compiler sees that there is an implicit conversion from `B` to `int`, and an implicit (built-in) conversion from `int` to `decimal`, so that it can use both in sequence. In other words, the call becomes `D((decimal)(int)b)`.

Note that nothing is being truncated; rather, an `int` is being promoted to a `decimal`. If instead you comment out the `int` conversion, I expect that `I(b)` will fail, since even though there is an implicit cast from `B` to `decimal`, there is no implicit cast from `decimal` to `int`.

Comment: I think you're right - i thought it would not compile bec. D(2.5) did not compile, but I just tried D(2.5m) and sure enough it worked... thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel: Probably because `2.5` is a `double`, as you apparently realized :-)

Answer (score 1):

when you comment that line out it takes the int operator because there is an implicit conversion of int to decimal...