# Why is double implicitly converted to int in a cast operator?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

This is strange behaviour that I haven't noticed before. I expected not to be able to cast from a `double` but instead the `double` value is implicitly converted to an `int` and I silently lose the fractional portion. Can I really not convert from `int`s without also converting from `double`s?

```
readonly struct TestDecimal {
   public decimal Value { get; }

   TestDecimal(decimal value) => 
      Value = value;

   public static explicit operator TestDecimal(int x) => new(x);
}

...

// these assertions fail, but really this shouldn't even compile
[TestMethod]
public void Test_CastFromDouble() {
   var value = (TestDecimal)12.34; // shouldn't compile
   Assert.AreEqual(12.34m, value.Value); // assertion failed, actual value: 12.0m
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test_CastFromDecimal() {
   var value = (TestDecimal)12.34m; // shouldn't compile
   Assert.AreEqual(12.34m, value.Value); // assertion failed, actual value: 12.0m
}
```

Comment: @Dai I cannot reproduce that. The IL says `ldc.i4.s 12`. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQA3AhgE4AEBEArgKbEC8xAFACqUDOwAIpQMZgC2+EAJTpUAOgDMAFgDcOHMTaFyXYMWZtOPfhGIBvecWLJxxGNz4DiANQFU9xAOaVg04gF852Q2tYdz2+jMtSzIqQVoAPmIDb2tbajpQyllsGOMjdAA2YkoADwAHCDAeVQB7fMpCfGBSknU/YIh6MAA7VVzwmiiWygB3eg6UtyA===)

Comment: @Sweeper I'm using Linqpad, and I get the same `ldc.i4.s` instruction. Remember that `lcd.i4.s` is for `int8` / `u8` / `byte` operands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4_s?view=net-7.0

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755178/why-does-implicit-conversion-to-int-convert-and-truncate-decimal

Comment: @Dai What type the `12` is, surely is an implementation detail?

Comment: The `12` is typed as `int8`.

Comment: @Jimi I was wrong - I assumed it would truncate _any_ `decimal` value to a single `int8`. Cheerfully withdrawn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because **[*standard conversions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#104-standard-conversions) can occur as part of a user-defined conversion**. Before your user-defined conversion, there can be a standard conversion converting the expression's type to the type your conversion operator expects. There can also be another standard conversion converting the return value of your conversion operator to whatever type is expected in that context.

[§10.5.3 Evaluation of user-defined conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1053-evaluation-of-user-defined-conversions)

> Once a most-specific user-defined conversion operator has been
> identified, the actual execution of the user-defined conversion
> involves up to three steps:
>
> - First, if required, performing a standard conversion from the source expression to the operand type of the user-defined or lifted
>   conversion operator.
> - Next, invoking the user-defined or lifted conversion operator to perform the conversion.
> - Finally, if required, performing a standard conversion from the result type of the user-defined conversion operator to the target
>   type.

This section then goes on to define terms such as *most-encompassing type*, which are then used in [§10.5.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1055-user-defined-explicit-conversions) to describe how exactly these conversions are resolved.

Most importantly for your case, the standard explicit conversions include "`double` to `int`" and "`decimal` to `int`". This enables you to call your conversion operator with `double`/`decimal` as arguments. See the language spec sections:

[§10.4.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1043-standard-explicit-conversions):

> The standard explicit conversions are all standard implicit
> conversions plus the subset of the explicit conversions for which an
> opposite standard implicit conversion exists.

Both "`double` to `int`" and "`decimal` to `int`" are "explicit conversions for which an opposite standard implicit conversion exists".

[§10.3.2 Explicit numeric conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1032-explicit-numeric-conversions):

> - ...
> - From `double` to `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, or `double`.
> - From `decimal` to `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, or `double`.
> - ...

[§10.4.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1042-standard-implicit-conversions)

> The following implicit conversions are classified as standard implicit
> conversions:
>
> - ...
> - Implicit numeric conversions (§10.2.3)

[§10.2.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1023-implicit-numeric-conversions):

> The implicit numeric conversions are:
>
> - ...
> - From `int` to `long`, `float`, `double`, or `decimal`.
> - ...

Comment: The linked articles describe `double` to `int` - and `int` to `decimal` - but not `decimal` to `int`.

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I forgot about the second example in the question and the quotes are a bit incomplete. It should be fixed now.

Comment: I suspected it was something like this, but it sure seems wrong that explicit conversions can be used.